# HTML5 structure and headings in section or article

Tags: html

Although I should really know this, I am afraid that I don't get it completely. Having read different articles, read books and spoke to others I still don't quite understand the correct structure for a HTML5 `section`. Is it appropriate to have a `h1` tag within each `section` and/or `article`? Does a new `section` or `article` constitute starting the `h1` to `h2` process again?

I am under the impression that each "block" should be allowed it's own "heading" structure.

For example, is this correct HTML5? :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>
    <!-- etc. etc. -->

    <body>
      <section> <!-- two or more <articles> within this section, both using <h1> tags -->
        <h1>Here is a section with articles in</h1>
        <article>
          <h1>Heading</h1>
          <h2>sub heading</h2>
          <p>A paragraph>
        </article>
        <article>
          <h1>Heading</h1>
          <h2>sub heading</h2>
          <p>A paragraph</p>
        </article>
        ...      
      </section>
      <section> <!-- two or more <articles> within this additional section, both using <h1> tags -->
        <h1>Here is a section with articles in</h1>
        <article>
          <h1>Heading</h1>
          <h2>sub heading</h2>
          <p>A paragraph>
        </article>
        <article>
          <h1>Heading</h1>
          <h2>sub heading</h2>
          <p>A paragraph</p>
        </article>
        ...      
      </section>                  
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since each pair of `h1` and `h2` elements in your `article`s represents a heading and a subheading respectively, you'll need to group the pair into its own `header` within the `article` in order to generate a proper document outline for each article.

Besides that, the heading structures of your sections seem fine.

Comment: @beingalex: Actually, it'd depend on what you're using your subheadings for: as chapter headings in each article, or as a subtitle for the entire article. If you have more than one chapter represented by its own `h2`, you probably don't want to group `h1` and `h2` together.

Comment: I run into the same problems when deciding on how to structure my document with HTML5. I always go back to this reference http://html5doctor.com/outlines/ to help me visual the document